# How to use a node module outside of node?

Tags: node.js, command-line, npm

I installed the sass node module through npm and want to use it to compile some scss stylesheets which are not in a node environment.

Ideally I want to be able to use it like the coffeescript compiler

sass -cw somestylesheet.scss

But anything that gets me close to there will do.

I don't see any commandline utility. Is there some sort of standard way to do this sort of thing with node?

Comment: I didn't find any command line wrappers for the 2 different node SASS ports I found. You could write one and contribute it, I guess. LESS does come with a command line interface: https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js as does stylus https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus

Comment: @PeterLyons is this it? https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/bin/lessc

Comment: Yup, that's it. And in general you can write javascript programs for node.js that are runnable from the command line. Works just like perl, python, ruby in that regard, just not every npm module comes with a command line tool. `#!/usr/bin/env node` at the top of a .js file works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you're already hacking together a little sass-compiler script, but here is some more background info:

To install a module globally in node using npm, npm reads the `"bin"` hash in `package.json`, to find a number of global names mapped to their corresponding scripts.

Here is an example I took from express:

```
{
  "name" : "express"
  ...
  "bin": { "express": "./bin/express" },
  ...
}
```

This tells npm to make the express script globally available, when you install the package with `npm install -g <package-name>`

I've checked https://github.com/andrew/node-sass/blob/master/package.json and it has no `"bin"` hash in its package.json, so you'll have to write one yourself.

As @peter-lyons has said, you start an executable node script with

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

your code
```

depending on the operating system you are using, you might also have to make the script executable with `chmod +x yourScript`. Then you should just be able to execute your script from any console, if you either put it on the global path, or if you call it as `./yourScript`.

Comment: Back in july I had just given up and used ruby. Coming back to it now with a new machine I'd still like to use node but dang - same pickle. I've got more node experience but not enough to know how to write my own wrapper especially on windows